# Can't find Ruby library file or shared library cocoapods

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I am trying to run an old react-native project(build successfully on another system 4 months ago). now I have clone that project into another system. but I got multiple issue. I deleted all setting from the system. home-brew, ruby, cocapoads and then install all one by one, but now getting this issue while run the command `pod install`

```
 Could not find 'rexml' (>= 0) among 115 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5:/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/specifications/CFPropertyList-3.0.6.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information


/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:314:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rexml' (>= 0) among 115 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5:/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec' , execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1456:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1426:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1462:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1426:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1462:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1444:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1426:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```